# image/intervention: blank image generated from jpg/png when convert into webp

Tags: php, laravel-5, amazon-s3, file-upload

I've created webp image using image/intervention. It's working perfectly on my local server but it's not working in the live server(Linux). Content-Type: image/webp and file-size is also correct. It displays from the mobile side but not in any browser.

create a blank image like this: https://imgur.com/a/CMx6tsU

I'm using following code to generate webp image from png/jpg:

```
$path = "path_of_original_png/jpg_image";
$webp_path= "path_to_save_webp_image";
$webp = Image::make($path);
$webp->save($webp_path, 75);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue in GD driver which is used in your server.
Now I used "https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/". It's perfect.