# S3 creates blank transparent webp image

Tags: php, laravel-5, amazon-s3

I have uploaded `webp` image into `Amazon-S3`. But sometimes it generates a blank transparent `webp` image. `Content-Type:image/webp` and `file-size` are also correct. Also, note that it displays from the mobile application but not in any browser. All is working fine on the local server. Problems occur in only with the live server. I've used the following code:

```
$disk = Storage::disk('s3');
$original_targetFile = "videoflyer/webp_original/" . $image;
$disk->put($original_targetFile, file_get_contents($original_sourceFile), 
'public');
```

S3 generates a blank image like this:

https://imgur.com/a/CMx6tsU

Comment: doesn't it work in chrome?

Comment: No, It's not work in chrome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [image/intervention: blank image generated from jpg/png when convert into webp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51587555/image-intervention-blank-image-generated-from-jpg-png-when-convert-into-webp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it's my miss understanding. There is an issue of GD driver.
Now I am using `https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/` & it's work perfectly.